# Try/Catch block in Main method only works in debugger

Tags: c#, winforms, try-catch

I have a problem (C#, WinForm):
There is a code (Program.cs):

> static void Main()
>   {
>       try
>       {
>           Application.Run(new Form());
>       }
>       catch (Exception e)
>       {
>           // Do Something. (with e, too)
>       }
>   }

When I run a code from VisualStudio, the try-catch block works fine.
But If I run the code outside of VisualStudio, the default error message will be thrown, and a try-catch block not runs.

When I tried, I used an Dictionary and I called an undefinied key, and that throw the exception. (in Form1.cs)
I have tried removing the (Exception e) part.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What are you wanting to do when you catch the exception?

Comment: depends what exception are you facing ?